# Is it possible to add google admob in winRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, admob, ads

Is the sdk available for google admob for windows 8? Or is there any other way to include the admob in windows 8 apps?

Comment: Ad Mob for windows 8 is in the beta stage. AdMob members are not revealing the ETA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No , it's only available to Windows Phone 7

check the list of the SDKs : https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

if you are looking for **good alternative** there are : http://www.adduplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

inMobi has released sdk's for Windows phone 8 and Windows 8 RT. 
download it from:
www.inmobi.com 
or direct download link:
https://www.inmobi.com/AdvancedAdCode/InMobi_windows_SDK.zip

Hope this may help.

Comment: but inmobi isn't admob. The question is about adding admob, not ANY ad network